# SQL add to select the sum of equal values

Tags: sql-server

```
    SELECT              
        hg.referencia AS Referencia,
        hg.toleInf AS Min,
        hg.toleSup AS Max,
        ROUND(CAST((hrg.x1+hrg.x2+hrg.x3+hrg.x4)/4  AS FLOAT),2) AS X,
        COUNT(hg.Referencia) AS NumGraficos
    FROM hRegGeometrias hrg
    JOIN hGeometria hg 
    ON hrg.idGeometria = hg.idGeom
    WHERE hrg.idMatriz = 2
    GROUP BY hg.referencia, hg.toleInf, hg.toleSup, hrg.x1, hrg.x2, hrg.x3, hrg.x4, hrg.idRegisto
    ORDER BY Referencia, IdRegisto ASC
```

which returns this

[image]

what i expect is that it sums the column Referencia but only distinct value, like for example, the sum should be 2 because there's only

```
'M130342'
'M130344'
```

So in the column NumGraficos, i would expect the value to be 2.

How to achieve this?

```
Referencia  Min Max X   NumGraficos
M130342     2   7   9,81    1
M130342     2   7   9,8     1
M130342     2   7   3,25    1
M130342     2   7   1,75    1
M130342     2   7   3,13    1
M130344     1   7   2       1
M130344     1   7   4,75    1
M130344     1   7   3,25    1
```

**EDIT**

It's probably impossible to get the result I expect since this database relations are messed up. I will try a different approach by returning some values separatedly

Comment: What was returned ? I can't see images.

Comment: check again please

Comment: There is no mention of SUM in your SQL. Do you mean to use the word GROUP? 

If you only want one instance of referencia you need to look at the X column as this is causing you to get multiple rows back.

Comment: I need to return all records though.

Comment: So the issue is that the X column is returning too many values? If that's the case you'd need to reevaluate the logic you write to calculate X. It's not clear what you're requesting when you write "I would expect the value to be 2"

Comment: Yes I know what I'm asking probably does not make sense. I did not do this database and I understand the relations are messed up. I will try another approach

Comment: better to share base raw data ,  and it seems for NumGraficos , you need to find out the number of refrencias used when generating  table ,  try using  this NumGraficos  to be computed from other select query as this would remain a single value??

Comment: yeah thats what i thought, but i think it's better to get referencias first, than get the rest of the data and use it as a nested object on my application